# post & clear filter -Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I need to clear filter after search
Here is my **index.cshtml**

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchNom" value="@ViewData["sNom"]?.ToString()" class="form-control" id="nom" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchPrenom" value="@ViewData["sPrenom"]?.ToString()" id="prenom" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchEmail" value="@ViewData["sEmail"]?.ToString()" id="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="search" name="searchTelephone" value="@ViewData["sTelephone"]?.ToString()" id="telephone" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <button class="btn" type="reset" id="reset" onclick="Reset()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and then **the action Index:**

```
   public string searchNom { get; set; }
        public string searchPrenom { get; set; }
        public string searchEmail { get; set; }
        public string searchTelephone { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchNom, string searchPrenom, string searchEmail, string searchTelephone, int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
        {
            
            if (searchNom != null || searchPrenom != null || searchEmail != null || searchTelephone != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;

            }
            

            var personnels = from s in _context.personnels
                             select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPrenom) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmail) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTelephone))
            {
                personnels = personnels.Where(s => s.Nom.Equals(searchNom) || s.Prenom.Equals(searchPrenom) || s.Email.Equals(searchEmail) || s.Telephone.Equals(searchTelephone));
                ViewData["sNom"] = searchNom ;
                ViewData["sPrenom"] = searchPrenom;
                ViewData["sEmail"] = searchEmail;
                ViewData["sTelephone"] =searchTelephone ;
                
            }

            else
            {
                ViewData["sNom"] = "";
                ViewData["sPrenom"] = "";
                ViewData["sEmail"] = "";
                ViewData["sTelephone"] = "";
            }
          
            
                int pageSize = 20;
            return View(await Pagination<PersonnelModel>.CreateAsync(personnels.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));


        }
```

js code:

```
<script>
    function Reset() {
        document.getElementById("nom").value = "";
        document.getElementById("prenom").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("telephone").value = "";


    }</script>
```

Now the problem ,the button reset dosen't work ther is an exception Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selectedIndex' of null
at Reset ((index):357)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):107)

Is there any way how to  make "reset" button working on form data values in same time please?

Thank you very much in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The code above can't be executed as we don't have the `_context` variable, nor the `PersonelModel` class.

The way you use `ViewData` to initially populate the form seems a little shady - I'd make sure I pass the view model instead. I appreciate that this is not the issue here.

Answering the actual question, I'd start with wrapping the script functions with

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
});
```

or have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Instead of depending on `onclick` attribute, have a look at `.click()` function from jQuery library, have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp)

Using the above, your code will look something like:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("nom").value = "";
    document.getElementById("prenom").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("telephone").value = "";
});
```

given you added submit-button id to your button.

Comment: thanks for reply,i found the solution,I do this code here below

Comment: no problem amal51. please consider using .click() from jQuery as on the above edit. If I helped you, please marked my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution finally ,i added this document.forms["form"].submit(); also

```
   <script>
        function Reset() {

            document.getElementById("nom").value = "";
            document.getElementById("prenom").value = "";
            document.getElementById("email").value = "";
            document.getElementById("telephone").value = "";
            document.forms["form"].submit();

        }</script>
```